# Can't create zvol due to "out of space" although there is enough space left

Tags: zfs

On one of my servers, I am running ZFS - no issues during two years. However, today I wanted to create an additional zvol, which only lead to an error message stating we were "out of space". The weird thing is that there definitely *is* enough space:

```
root@cerberus:/vm-images# zfs list -r -t all
NAME            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool           956G   842G    96K  none
rpool/stretch   926G   842G   926G  /
rpool/swap     29.8G   869G  2.82G  -

root@cerberus:/vm-images# zfs create -b 512 -o checksum=on -o compression=off -o primarycache=none -o redundant_metadata=all -o secondarycache=none -o logbias=latency -o snapdev=hidden -o sync=standard -V 600G rpool/vm-garak
cannot create 'rpool/vm-garak': out of space
```

So we have 842 GB of space available, but it refuses to create a zvol with 600 GB in size.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT 1 (as per request of @Jim L.):

No reservations are in use:

```
root@cerberus:/vm-images# zfs list -o name,reservation -r
NAME           RESERV
rpool            none
rpool/stretch    none
rpool/swap       none
```

Comment: Any reservations in use?  Edit your post to include the output of: `zfs list -o name,reservation -r`

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited my question. No reservations are in use.

Comment: I'm not yet sure why it's a problem, but try it without the `-b 512`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is really interesting. Now that we (i.e. you) have found the actual cause of the problem, there are two things left to do: 1) For you: Make the comment an answer so that I can accept it :-) 2) For me: Find a way to make it work with block size 512, because I have read articles which recommend to give any zvol the same blocksize as the underlying disks have. Any comments on that (I'll probably make this an own question)?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly a separate question.  When you post it, be sure to include a link to the authority you're citing as the source of that claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `-b` option appears to increase the space consumed by the ZVOL in inverse proportion to the blocksize specified.  At `-b 512` I see about a 50% inflation in the size, so your 600G ZVOL would require approx. 900G free space.

I'll use a smaller example on my laptop, which has far less space available, but the ratios are similar for `-b 512`:

```
# zfs list
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank   191G  38.0G    88K  none
(...snip...)
# zfs create -b 512 -V 30g tank/zvol
cannot create 'tank/zvol': out of space
# zfs create -b 512 -V 24g tank/zvol
# zfs list tank/zvol
NAME        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/zvol  36.0G  38.0G    56K  -
```

At `-b 512` the ZVOL takes up 50% more space than it offers as storage.  But at `-b 128k` for example, the overhead is much lower:

```
# zfs destroy tank/zvol
# zfs create -b 128k -V 36g tank/zvol
# zfs list tank/zvol
NAME        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/zvol  36.1G  38.0G    56K  -
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/548 discusses the interaction between volblocksize (-b) and ashift.

Is this zfsonlinux or solaris (solaris 11 doesn't support setting ashift - it is as it is) ?

What do zpool status says ?

is the pool raidz ?

Comment: Thanks for caring, and thanks for the link - I'll have a deep look into it. This is ZoL (ZFS on Linux), and I am using a mirror vdev (so no raidz). zpool status does not report any problems.