# zvol taking (way) too much space, depending on block size

Tags: zfs

Today, [I stumbled across a weird problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586186/cant-create-zvol-due-to-out-of-space-although-there-is-enough-space-left?noredirect=1#comment1091846_586186) where I couldn't create a zvol, because ZFS claimed there was not enough space left, although there *was* enough space.

It turned out that a zvol obviously takes up more than 150% of the space expected, depending on its blocksize. For example, in the situation I have described in the question linked above, I could create a zvol with no more than 560 GB if using a block size of 512 bytes, although the available space was 842 GB. However, I could create a zvol with 810 GB with no problem when using the default block size (which is 8 kB).

The helpful person who answered the other question verified my results by doing own measurements and also saw that increase in size by 50% if using a blocksize of 512 Bytes.

I would like to know why this is, and if I could get around it somehow.

Background:

Normally, I wouldn't care about the block size too much. However, I have read at least two articles whose authors recommend giving a zvol the same block size as the underlying disks have, especially if that zvols are being used as VM storage. Unfortunately, I only can remember one of those sources, but at least it is the one where the author proved (somehow) his claims by benchmarks. Here it is (please have a look into section "Dataset"):

https://martin.heiland.io/2018/02/23/zfs-tuning/

If trying to make a zvol's block size the same as the sector size of the physical disks is nonsense, I wouldn't mind if that would be clearly stated in an answer :-)

Personally, I guess that we would have to read the source code to decide if it makes sense, or to do our own benchmarks (which is not possible for me at the moment, because I don't have enough space on that system ...). I could also imagine that it would even be better to make the zvol block size match the *cluster size of the VM guest file system* (in case the VM uses NTFS, which is the case with the VM in question and some others I use).

Comment: Does this help understand it? [strange ZFS disk space usage report for a ZVOL](https://serverfault.com/questions/512018/strange-zfs-disk-space-usage-report-for-a-zvol)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting answer - the answer suggests the opposite than the article I have linked. However, this answer does not look into performance, only into space consumption. I'll have to think about it for a while.